# Sharing multiple values or an object through contexts

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to share user-entered form data with a component that shows a "preview" of the formatted content. Similar to StackOverflow showing the markdown preview below this text-entry box, however in my case the data comes from multiple text fields.

To sync the data, I'm using a context (which appears to be the correct approach based on my research) but my problem is that I'm not sure how to share multiple values.

I figured each form field could send data as part of an object that for the *receiving* component, might look like this:

```
{
    firstname: (input from first name field component)
    address: (input from address field component)
    other: (input from other field component)
}
```

The receiving component can then just read this data `{preview.firstname}`.

When setting the value after a user has updated the field, I use the spread operator to combine existing data into a new object.

However, I get the feeling this is a problematic way to do this. The linter complains that the `preview` object is not in the `useEffect` dependencies, but if I put it there, it creates an infinite render loop.

```
const [field] = useField('firstname');
const { preview, setPreview } = useContext(MyContext);

useEffect(() => {
    setPreview({
        ...preview,
        name: field.value
    });
}, [field.value, setPreview]);
```

I guess I could create a different context for each form field but that will get verbose and I don't think that's the right solution either.

I'm still learning React/Contexts so I'm unsure what the "right" solution is. Do I use one context for each "state" value I want to share, or can I share a "state" object safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use functional set state:

```
  setPreview(ps=>({
        ...ps,
        name: field.value
    }));
```

No need for `preview` as dependency anymore.